# Convert a string (is in an array format) to array in php

Tags: php

In my project I have to convert a string which is in array format:

```
$str = "array(array('text', 'Video Code', 0, 'videoCode', '', 'Paste the youtube Video Code'))";
```

Is there any way to convert it to an array like:

```
$array = array(array('text', 'Video Code', 0, 'videoCode', '', 'Paste the youtube Video Code'));
```

Note: The array may be more than 10th dimensional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// if format of the string is like
$str = "array(array('text', 'Video Code', 0, 'videoCode', '', 'Paste the youtube Video Code'))";
// Make json format from it
$str = str_replace(['array(', ')', "'"], ['[',']', '"'], $str);
// And decode
print_r(json_decode($str, true));
```

result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => text
            [1] => Video Code
            [2] => 0
            [3] => videoCode
            [4] => 
            [5] => Paste the youtube Video Code
        )
)
```

Comment: Processing it to JSON then using json_decode() is actually a very smart idea. I'd use this one OP.

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`eval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php), but it's not recommended to use on public data.

```
$str = "\$arr = array(array('text', 'Video Code', 0, 'videoCode', '', 'Paste the youtube Video Code'));";
eval($str);
print_r($arr);
```

From PHP Manual:

> Caution The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it
>   allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged.
>   If you have carefully verified that there is no other option than to
>   use this construct, pay special attention not to pass any user
>   provided data into it without properly validating it beforehand.

Comment: As you have pointed I can't use it and it sometimes not provided in the shared hosting... Anyway thank you it's a new trick for me...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$str = "array(array('text', 'Video Code', 0, 'videoCode', '', 'Paste the youtube Video Code'))";
$str = trim($str,"array(");
$str = trim($str,")");
$arr = explode(",",$str);
$arr_final = array();
$arr_final[] = $arr;
print '<pre>';print_r($arr_final);
```

Comment: Sir your answer correct but it is limited to that array (I mean array of array), as I have written the array may be more than 10th dimensional...
But it can also be tweaked by for loop or by stack to achieve my result... Thank you.